# How to use loop for in gulp?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, gulp

I am trying to automate file creation in gulp. I made a prepare task that should take section names from an array and generate files with built-in markup inside:

```js
function prepare(){
  for(let i = 0; i==sections.length-1;i++){
    return createFile(`src/parts/_${sections[i]}.html`, `
    <div class="${sections[i]}">
      <div class="${sections[i]}__content ${sections[i]}__container"></div>
    </div>\n`, 
    function (err) {
      // file either already exists or is now created (including non existing directories)
    });
  }
}
```

But this error comes out:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yM0N.png)

It means the lack of return in the function. How to execute a for loop creating files and still use return?

Comment: An unconditional return statement in a for loop doesn't make sense. It will always return in the first iteration.

Comment: The loop `for(let i = 0; i==sections.length-1;i++){` doesn't make any sense, too. It will either iterate once for `sections.length === 1` or be completely skipped.

Comment: but why? there is array "sections" with as example 3 elements

Comment: what am i doing wrong?

Comment: The condition in `for(let i = 0; i==2;i++){` is wrong for the initial value `i = 0` and the loop is skipped. It looks like you should read about [for loops](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

Comment: but the condition is wrong? I dont understand. And how should i use "return" with my for loop

Comment: `0 == 2` is obviously false.

Comment: but how can i use "return"?

Comment: One way to wait for multiple promises is to store all promises in an array and wait for `Promise.all(...)`. What is `createFile` and what does it return?

Comment: its npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/create-file that creating new html files

Comment: What does it return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert an existing callback API to promises?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22519784/how-do-i-convert-an-existing-callback-api-to-promises)

Comment: nothing. Just creates files (sorry im newbie in gulp)

Comment: Why do you return it? The callback function is called when the file is created. You could count the calls and call the `done` function that is passed to `prepare`.

Comment: ok i added "done()" and use promise, there is no error more but files are not created

Comment: Your loop condition is wrong.

Comment: brooo thank you so much i fixed it and files was created. I use promise, done() and replace "for (i = 0; i==sections.length-1; i++) " to "let i = 0;for (i; i<sections.length; i++)"

Comment: I thank you very much. Good luck to you!